# Invalid Syntax when importing ServiceAccountCredentials from oauth2client.service_account

Tags: python, aws-lambda, oauth2client

I'm trying to `import ServiceAccountCredentials` from `oauth2client.service_account` in my AWS-Lambda code but it keeps on giving me the error `Invalid Syntax`.

I run the normal code in my own PC and the code works, but when I move the code into my AWS-Lambda, it gives me the `Invalid Syntax` error. I already added all the libraries needed into my AWS Lambda layer.

```py
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
```

it gives an error :

```
START RequestId: 42276808-a49f-45ea-a955-b19206197c87 Version: $LATEST
Syntax error in module 'handler': invalid syntax (__init__.py, line 475)

END RequestId: 42276808-a49f-45ea-a955-b19206197c87
REPORT RequestId: 42276808-a49f-45ea-a955-b19206197c87  Duration: 0.33 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 54 MB
```

Even if I am only importing the library it gives me an error.
Is there another way I can import or use `ServiceAccountCredentials`?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I use the wrong Python version runtime in my aws-lambda haha.
I used Python 2.7 but it should've been Python 3.6.